# How to update results with start date and end date inputed from user

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I have a table with dates and name and I have 2 dates Datum1 and Datum2 when users insert to limit the results between those 2 dates but it does not work.This 2 dates are in separated model and I have created separate controller. I do not need to save those dates in my database just to limit the outputs Here is my controller:

```
   [HttpGet]
    // GET: PregledPoDatumu
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DataTable dtblRezultat = new DataTable();
        PregledPoDatumu pregledPoDatumu = new PregledPoDatumu();
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(
             ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestCS"].ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Kontrola ORDER BY Datum", sqlCon);
            sqlDa.Fill(dtblRezultat);

        }

        return View(dtblRezultat);
    }


    [HttpGet]

    // GET: PregledPoDatumu/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new PregledPoDatumu());
    }

    // POST: PregledPoDatumu/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PregledPoDatumu pregledPoDatumu)
    {

        DataTable dtblRezultat = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestCS"].ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            if (pregledPoDatumu.Datum1 > pregledPoDatumu.Datum2)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Datum1", "start date must be before end date");
                return View();
            }
            if(pregledPoDatumu.Datum1 > DateTime.Now)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Datum1", "Unesite datum prije današnjeg");
                return View();
            }
            if(pregledPoDatumu.Datum2 > DateTime.Now)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Datum2", "Unesite datum do današnjeg");
                return View();
            }
            if(pregledPoDatumu.Datum1 == DateTime.MinValue){
                ModelState.AddModelError("Datum1", "Unesite datum ");
                return View();
            }
            if (pregledPoDatumu.Datum2 == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Datum2", "Unesite datum ");
                return View();
            }






            string query = "SELECT * FROM Kontrola where Datum > @Datum1 and Datum < @Datum2";
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlCon);
            sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum1", pregledPoDatumu.Datum1);
            sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum2", pregledPoDatumu.Datum2);
            sqlDa.Fill(dtblRezultat);


        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

What should I change,so when user enters 1/1/2014 and 1/1/2017 to show only results between those 2 dates? In this case I have done my table does not refresh and still shows all the results in the table?

Model:

```
namespace WebApplication6.Models
{
    public class PregledPoDatumu
    {
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Datum1 { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Datum2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. The code you posted does not relate to the question you asked.

Comment: Can you show us your `PregledPoDatumu` model?

Comment: Hi, I have added the model. Do you need anything else?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `return RedirectToAction("Index")` in the Post method. What this is doing is redirecting to index but you are not passing the filtered data table.

To fix this you could change to `return View("Index", dtblRezultat)`, this will return the `Index` view from the Post method and pass the datatable `dtblRezultat` to the view.

There are other options too, you could modify the `Index` action to take date parameters (or a model) and do the filtering in the `Index` action.